# C++ shuffle on map(string, string)

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, shuffle

I'm writing some small dictionary + quiz program. I have almost everything ready, but now when it comes to the QUIZ I need to use shuffle. How can I use map(string, string)?

I have a `map<string, string> slowka;` (it contains pairs of POL and ENG words).

Comment: If by shuffle you mean you want to get random questions for quiz, generate a random number and use it to fetch the question from the map.

Answer (score 2):

Don't shuffle a `map`, shuffle a `std::vector` of questions (likely `pair<string,string>`) . The original map could still be useful to check quiz answers.

Comment: For turning a map into a vector, all map iterators return map::value_type which is pair<string,string>; add all such pairs to a vector. For shuffling a vector, std::shuffle

Comment: I know it's lazy approach, but can you show me code? I don't know how to do this.